# Why is .ix inclusive on the end of indexing ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Python Version: 2.7.6
Numpy Version: 1.10.2
Pandas: 0.17.1

I understand that .ix is now deprecated, but I'm working on a legacy system and seeing this behavior with .ix and I'm preplexed

```
# Native Python List Indexing is exclusive on the end index
[0, 1, 2, 3][0:1] # returns [0] indexes with [0, 1)
# Native Numpy
import numpy as np
numpyArray = np.reshape(np.arange(4), (2, 2))
numpyArray[0:1, 0:1] # returns array([[0]]), indexes with [0, 1) in rows and [0, 1) in columns
####### Pandas #######
import pandas as pd
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(numpyArray) 
# Pandas with iloc #
dataFrame.iloc[0:1, 0:1] # returns 0, indexes with [0, 1) in rows and [0, 1) in columns
# Pandas with ix #
dataFrame.ix[0:1, 0:1] # returns [[0, 1], [2, 3] indexes with [0, 1] in rows and [0, 1] in columns
```

Comment: It's because it's label-based indexing which is designed to include the stop value, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) is label-based indexing (same as `.loc`) which the docs state includes the stop range value which is different to `iloc` which is open-closed range so doesn't include the stop range value, this is by design

The reason it does this is because if your indices were for instance string, then it would make it problematic to select a range where you didn't know what the end range value should be:

```
In[274]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'), index=list('vwxyz'))
df

Out[274]: 
          a         b         c
v -0.488627  0.213183  0.224104
w -0.200328 -1.138937  0.815568
x -1.131868 -0.562758  0.088719
y  0.120701 -0.863737  0.246295
z -0.808140  0.253376  0.645974

In[275]:
df.ix['w':'y']

Out[275]: 
          a         b         c
w -0.200328 -1.138937  0.815568
x -1.131868 -0.562758  0.088719
y  0.120701 -0.863737  0.246295
```

If it didn't include the end value for the last row, you'd need to know that `'z'` had to be passed in order to return the label before `'z'` to get the result above

**update**

Note that [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) is deprecated since `0.20.1` and you should use `loc`